# how to correlate using groovy code in jmeter?

Tags: groovy, jmeter

```
    1) In my response body comes like json format.
    2) Some expected reason ,i have changed that body json to normal text using below code and working expected way          
                 import groovy.json.*
                 String js = vars.get("cAccountDetails")
                 def data = new JsonSlurper().parseText(js)
                 log.info("the value is "+ data)
                 vars.putObject('data', data) 
    3) This code meaning converted json to normal text and stored in some variable thats "data"
    4) so my response stored in "data" variable .
    5) From "data", how can i extract **specific data** using groovy code or some other code?
           import java.util.regex.*
           import java.util.regex.Matcher
           import java.util.regex.Pattern
           def matches = (data =~ '{accountDetails=\\[(.*)\\],')
           vars.putObject('matches', matches)
```

The above code using for correlation purpose {"matches" VARIABLE will store extracted value}

7. but above code is not working ,how can i fix this issue ?

   ```
    Thanks in advance!!
   ```

Comment: I WANT EXTRACT FROM "data" variable and i have attached response body  ****data={accountDetails=[{SUMMA=456451, AccountId=122, networkedLPLAccountID=null, isLPLAccount=1, isShellAccount=0, FHHEBFRJH=21231231, isClosed=1, sponsoredAccounts=[]}],***

Answer (score 0):

We cannot help you unless you share your `cAccountDetails` variable value and indicate what do you need to extract from it.

From the first glance you regular expression should look a little bit different, i.e.

```
def matches = (data =~ /accountDetails=[(.*)],/)
```

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Find Operator](https://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_find_operator)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: "accountDetails": [
      {
        "accountClassName": "Brokerage - Retirement",
        "residentAddress": "Queen Anne Dr",
        "mailingAddress": " QUEEN  DR",
        "mobilePhone": null,
        "sponsoredAccounts": [
         ]
      },
       {
        "mailingAddress": "  ANNE DR",
        "homePhone": "48484848585"
        "mobilePhone": null,
        "sponsoredAccounts": [
         ]
      },
      {
        "accountClassName": " - Retirement",
        "residentAddress": " Queen Anne ",
        "sponsoredAccounts": [
         ] 
          }
    ],

Comment: Answer Please ???